# c++ concepts require method with badge (privately-constructible) argument

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

I would like to define a concept where a class is a required to have a method that takes a Badge argument. Badges are used to restrict access to a method to the type specified by the badge, instead of making them full-blown friends calling a private method:

```
template <typename Owner>
class Badge
{
    friend Owner;
    Badge(void) = default; //private, only Owner can construct
};
```

So for a class BadgeHolder, my concept looks like this:

```
struct BadgeHolder {};

template <typename Object>
concept HasRestricted = requires(Object aObject)
{
    aObject.Restricted_Public_Method(Badge<BadgeHolder>{});
};
```

However using this concept doesn't compile:

```
struct MyClass
{
    void Restricted_Public_Method(Badge<BadgeHolder>){}
};

template <HasRestricted Object>
void DoIt(Object& aObject)
{
}

int main()
{
    MyClass cInstance;
    DoIt(cInstance);
    return 0;
}
```

With compiler error (from gcc):

```
<source>:16:38: error: 'constexpr Badge<Owner>::Badge() [with Owner = BadgeHolder]' is private within this context
   16 |     aObject.Restricted_Public_Method(Badge<BadgeHolder>{});
```

How can I build this concept?  Making the Badge constructor public works but that defeats the point of the badge. [Link](https://godbolt.org/z/rP3YPzrqv) to godbolt.

Comment: You could use `std::declval<Badge<BadgeHolder>>()` instead of `Badge<BadgeHolder>{}` in your concept to make it compile. However, I'm not sure what exactly you were trying to achieve.

Comment: Don’t declare functions with `(void)`, please.  That’s a C89 thing that should have died long ago.